# Format numeric symbols in titles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I add title post as: `this - is - post`

I view code source : `this &#8211; is &#8211; post`

How to format code source as: `this - is - post`

Error: I'm user jQuery UI autocomplete code source [`"this &#8211; is &#8211; post"`,`"this &#8211; is &#8211; post"`, ] and views html autocomplete input is `this &#8211; is &#8211; post`

How to fix in jQuery or change echo code source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress makes number of typographical replacements, related to dashes. You can read through the [How WordPress Handles Dashes and Hyphens](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-wordpress-handles-dashes-and-hyphens/) for full details, but in short your specific case is `[space][hyphen][space]` getting replaced with `[space][en-dash][space]`.

You will have to step through your code to make sense at which point it goes wrong and turns into visible unwanted entity rather than character.

Depending on how much of this you have the easy fix might be just to type actual en-dash character (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0150</kbd> on numpad on Windows) instead of "minus" hyphen.

Comment: Thanks! i'm used remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' ) and the questions done.